# Solving the energy spectrum for a $\cot^2$ potential well using the WKB approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical

I am taking graduate quantum mechanics, and we are now discussing the WKB/semiclassical approximation. I am trying to solve a problem where I would need to find the energy spectrum of the 1D motion in the following potential,
$$V(x) = V_0\cot^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{d} \right),\,  0<x<a.$$

I understand the fact that I would need to obtain the turning points where $E = V(x)$. I think those turning points would be $x_0 = \pm \frac{a}{\pi} \cot^{-1}\sqrt\frac{E}{V_0}$.

The problem I am facing though, it seems like is just the integration? If I plug this in into the phase formula,

$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\hbar} \int p(x)\,dx$

The integral is just horrific, which makes me think that this is not how I am supposed to approach this problem.

Comment: Is the $d$ value in your potential supposed to be $a$ or something else or is it completely independent of $a$.

Comment: @StephenG it is completely independent of a